# SoundCloud VIsual Player embedded code for Wordpress does not match preview

Tags: wordpress, soundcloud

About a week ago our visual players on our website all changed and the format has a distorted picture across the entire visual player.  I went to the soundcloud site and clicked the option to have the picture show in the left side... the preview is correct however when I transfer the Wordpress code into our site it is the same distorted view. If I copy in the iframe short code it works properly.  Which I can do going forward if necessary however for the hundreds we already have coded into our site that would take considerable effort.  Is there a know issue out on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default setting for SoundCloud embeds in the plugin settings. Go to WordPress Admin > Plugins > SoundCloud Shortcode > Settings > Widget Type and select HTML5.

[image: Preview]